# Any useful mathematical function / algorithm to break down big numbers?

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, factorization

So what I want to do is breaking down numbers that are dozens of thousands big into smaller numbers, preferably 2~9.

The first thing came to my mind was prime factorization, for instance the number 49392 can be expressed as (2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 3 x 3 x 7 x 7 x 7). But there are prime numbers and numbers such as 25378 =  2 × 12689 that cant be expressed with only multiplication.

So I want to break these numbers down using multiplication *and* addition, for example, the number 25378 could be expressed as 25346 + 32 = (2 × 19 × 23 × 29) + (2^5). Still, 23 and 29 are too big but I just picked random number just to show what I mean by using addtion and multiplication together to express big numbers, I'm sure there's a better combination of number that express 25378 than 25346 and 32.

Anyways, I thought programming this would involve ton of unnecessary if statement and would be incredibly slow in the big picture. So I was wondering, if there is a mathematical algorithm or function that does this thing? If not, I could just optimize the code myself, but I was just curious, I couldn't find anything on google myself though.

Comment: Why do you want to break them ? Just for fun ? What is "too big" ? You need to have a precise definition if you want an algorithm. One way would be to break it down into smaller number and them break those down if they are too big. But currently there is not that much to work on, because nothing is defined.

Comment: @AloisChristen Any number larger than 13 would be considered 'too big' but I would mostly use numbers that are in 20000s. It's for a silly little esolang project, though. That would work too, but as the numbers get bigger the amount of smaller numbers get exponentially bigger as well and end up being too long and complicated. I was wondering if there's any algorithm / formula that does this and also using the least amount of smaller numbers

Comment: If your question is how to express N as the simplest expression using only the numbers 2-9, and the operators + and *, then I believe there's no simpler algorithm than a search using dynamic programming. But the problem is underspecified at the moment -- are brackets allowed? How do you represent 0, 1? Can you really not use 1? You say that 11 is not too big, but it's also not composed of the numbers 2-9.

Comment: @PaulHankin Brackets are ok, and you can use 1 as well. 11 could be used but 2-9 are more preferred, and there would be no such case where I would have to represent the numbers 0 and 1.

Comment: 25378 = 2 * (5 + 4 * 7 * (5 + 7 * 8 * 8))

Comment: `function breakdown(n): if n < 13: { return n } else { q,r = quotient_and_remainder(n, 12); if r == 0: { return (breakdown(q), '*', 12) } else: {  return (breakdown(q), '*', 12, '+', r)}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the problem is to write a number as the simplest expression containing the numbers 1-9, addition and multiplication (simplest = smallest number of operators), then this Python program does this in O(N^2) time.

A number N can be written as the sum or product of two smaller numbers, so if you've precalculated the simplest way of constructing the numbers 1..N-1, then you can find the simplest way of constructing N in O(N) time. Then it's just a matter of avoiding duplicate work -- for example without loss of generality in the expressions A+B and AB, A<=B, and nicely printing out the final expression.

```
def nice_exp(x, pri):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return str(x)
    else:
        oppri = 1 if x[0] == '*' else 0
        if oppri < pri:
            bracks = '()'
        else:
            bracks = ['', '']       
        return '%s%s %s %s%s' % (bracks[0], nice_exp(x[1], oppri), x[0], nice_exp(x[2], oppri), bracks[1])

def solve(N):
    infinity = 1e12
    size = [infinity] * (N+1)
    expr = [None] * (N+1)
    for i in range(N+1):
        if i < 10:
            size[i] = 1
            expr[i] = i
            continue
        for j in range(2, i):
            if j * j > i: break
            if i%j == 0 and size[j] + size[i//j] + 1 < size[i]:
                size[i] = size[j] + size[i//j] + 1
                expr[i] = ('*', expr[j], expr[i//j])
        for j in range(1, i):
            if j > i-j: break
            if size[j] + size[i-j] + 1 < size[i]:
                size[i] = size[j] + size[i-j] + 1
                expr[i] = ('+', expr[j], expr[i-j])
    return nice_exp(expr[N], 0)

print(solve(25378))
```

Output:

```
2 * (5 + 4 * 7 * (5 + 7 * 8 * 8))
```

Comment: This is amazing, thanks a lot! By the way, iss there a particular name for this kind of process?

Comment: Note that this program allows "1" to appear as a number, for example 82=1 + 9*9. Without 1, the shortest solution is 82=2*(5+4+9) which is longer.

Comment: I don't think this has a name... it's just a bit of thought and some dynamic programming. It's a bit like the "countdown numbers game", but that has more complicated structure as a problem.

Comment: Given the program is slow once N gets in the tens of thousands range, you may want to run it for a large N, and print out all the results from the array rather than just for a single value of N. It should take a few minutes to run for N=100000, but then you have the answer for all numbers with 5 digits or fewer.

Comment: eg: https://gist.github.com/paulhankin/023035225be838ddc9af044ef22f0a2d

Comment: This definitely helped a lot, thank you!!

Comment: @Stef where does 1024 come from? You're right that this algorithm doesn't scale to numbers with lots of digits, but I don't think you have the sums right -- O(100^n) looks right to me. (The question includes the scale required -- "dozens of thousands" -- and the algorithm works slowly but acceptably for 100000).

Comment: @PaulHankin Indeed, a 10² turned into a 2^10 when I wasn't looking

Comment: I think it's worth noting that "this algorithm runs in O(N²), where N is the input number" is about the same as "this algorithm runs in O(100^n), where n is the number of digits of the input number", so be wary if your goal is to break down numbers that have lots of digits.